# login authentication from saved session in mysql (0,1)

Tags: database, prefix

i have

```
 foo.com 
 foo.com/foo
```

both sites are the same script.  main site have  `Prefix`  and second site have `Prefix_1`
they share one DB name same db_tables but connects upon the `Prefix` name. so both sites are executed in same mysql for different `prefix`

example table:

```
Prefix_users
Prefix_1_users
```

i manage that when registration from the main foo.com it will also update the `prefix_1` which are connected to foo.com/foo

in this way if someone register on foo.com he will be also able to login in foo.com/foo
successfully.

My question is, when session `start()` on foo.com and create `$session->value('user_id')` i want also to start on foo.com/foo so the same user dont need to login again on the other site foo.com/foo

i was thinking to save the session from foo.com into `prefix` and table `prefix_1`
and when user login from foo.com he will be also start the session from foo.com/foo

because they share one DB name , and same user name and password from 2 different table (different prefixed table )  but the session will not start on foo.com/foo
unless the user post the same user name and password again.

so any suggestions, 
this is the code

```
`<pre>session_start();
 define ('IN_SITE', 1);
 include_once ('includes/global.php');
 include_once ('includes/class_user.php');
 include_once ('includes/functions_login.php');
 if (!$session->value('user_id'))
 {
header_redirect('login.php');
 }
  else
  {
$template->set('session', $session);
(array) $summary_page_content = null;   
$default_landing_page = 'summary';
$default_landing_section = 'summary_main';</pre>`
```

The Idea IS Here-
 the idea is that from function_login.php   $is_login = $db->num_rows($login_query); are executed on that file and create the session and redirect to member_area.php , so i want to know how i can execute the code and start 2 sessions one for the foo.com/member_area.php and other session to be included for foo.com/foo/member_area.php

remember that both have same tables but different prefixes and both tables have the same user_id , user_name, password

Comment: This is not a very clear question.  What kind of session do you want to start?  It sounds like you mean a web server session, not a database session.

Comment: i want to create the $session->value('user_id') for both foo.com and foo.com/foo  when it start on the first foo.com then it has to start also on  foo.com/foo

Comment: If both sites are the same, it may be a much simpler thing to make foo.com point to the code at foo.com/foo so that there is really only 1 copy of your website running and you don't have these kinds of problems.